# Community Case Comments

Tags: community, case, customer-community, customer-portal, comments

So I am working on building out a support portal community and I have issues trying to figure out how I want to do case comments. I want our users to see our post that is visible to all and be able to submit their own posts. So I have found this component, BUT it is no longer available. So I need suggestions and help where to go.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_case_comments.htm&type=5

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The same link also says 'To continue using the Case Comments feature, make sure that the Case Comment related list is added to the case page layout used in communities.' did you try that out?

Comment: That component isn't listed in the community builder

Comment: My understanding from the documentation was it would appear in the detail layout of  case once you add it to the layout and not as a seperate lightning component in the builder

Comment: The Case Comments is a related list but the only thing I can put on a community is Case Comment Publisher. But there isn't anything I can see to see the comments.